# Filtering DataGridView VB

Tags: vb.net, filter

*note*: all column data is stored as nvarchar

My search function keeps giving me errors which I don't understand. Basically, I have a comboBox where the user can choose to filter the search to a specific column in the datagridview, then they can type their search in the textbox and click the button to search.

Types of errors I'm getting:
Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Native' operator. // I typed in the search textbox "Bold Native" and used the column filter "Films"
Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.String and System.Int32. // I typed in the search textbox "1979" and used the column filter "Year"

Very simple code, just a big if/elseif statement for each column of the database (excuse the dashes):

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    --If ComboBox1.Text = "          No Filter          " Then
     ----Me.FilmsBindingSource.Filter = Me.FilmsBindingSource.Filter = "Films LIKE " + TbFilter.Text + "% OR Actors LIKE " + TbFilter.Text + "% OR Directors LIKE " + TbFilter.Text + "% OR Writers LIKE " + TbFilter.Text
    --ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Films" Then
     ----Me.FilmsBindingSource.Filter = "Films LIKE " + TbFilter.Text
    --ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Year" Then
     ----Me.FilmsBindingSource.Filter = "Year LIKE " + TbFilter.Text
    --ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Duration" Then
        ----Me.FilmsBindingSource.Filter = "Duration LIKE " + TbFilter.Text
    --ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Actors" Then
        ----Me.FilmsBindingSource.Filter = "Actors LIKE " + TbFilter.Text
    --ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Directors" Then
        ----Me.FilmsBindingSource.Filter = "Directors LIKE " + TbFilter.Text
    --ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Writers" Then
        ----Me.FilmsBindingSource.Filter = "Writers LIKE " + TbFilter.Text
    --ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Own It?" Then
        ----Me.FilmsBindingSource.Filter = "Own It? LIKE " + TbFilter.Text
    --ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Seen it It?" Then
        ----Me.FilmsBindingSource.Filter = "Seen It? LIKE " + TbFilter.Text
    --ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Rating" Then
        ----Me.FilmsBindingSource.Filter = "Rating LIKE " + TbFilter.Text
    --ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Top 10" Then
        ----Me.FilmsBindingSource.Filter = "Top 10 LIKE " + TbFilter.Text
    --ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Misc" Then
        ----Me.FilmsBindingSource.Filter = "Misc LIKE " + TbFilter.Text
    --End If
End Sub
```

I'm trying to figure out a better way to filter/search but I haven't come up with any solutions yet. Any ideas?

Comment: What about this:     Private Function ApplyFilter(filterText As String)
        Dim filterString As String = String.Format("{0} LIKE {1}", ComboBox1.Text, filterText)
        Me.FilmsBindingSource.Filter = filterString
    End Function

Comment: Are you using a datatable to populate the grid? Do you have to use Filter?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this.

If the user does not select any item, it will search by ID. Otherwise, it will search by the selected field (criteria).

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles Button3.Click
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim criteria, value As String
    value = InputBox("Please enter value: ")
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        cmd= New SqlCommand("Select * from DATA Where ID=@id", Connection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", value)
    Else
        criteria = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from DATA where " & criteria _
                                   & " like '%" & value & "%' ", Connection)
    End If
    dtTable.Rows.Clear()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dtTable)
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dtTable
End Sub
```